# How to remove last segment in filepath in command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I am working on a batch application where I have to get the current directory path via command prompt.

I can get the file location as:

```
C:\Users\Username\Downloads\Images\dance.png
```

or current directory as:

```
C:\Users\Username\Downloads\Images\stock_images\
```

I have to get the desired directory path as:

```
C:\Users\Username\Downloads\Images\
```

I have looked around on stackoverflow for the solution but could not find something useful.

So, how can I get **parent directory** of a file or subdirectory using batch script?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted it a number of times, but can't locate it for the moment

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "name=C:\Users\Username\Downloads\Images\stock_images\dance.png"
FOR %%a IN ("%name%") DO FOR %%b IN ("%%~dpa.") DO ECHO Grandparent=%%~dpb&ECHO parent=%%~nxb
```